# Count members of an IHTMLCollection

Tags: html, vba, excel, dom

I got bogged down with a subject I know very little about: trying to scrape data from a web site using VBA. I'm not sure that I am hunting the correct hare, but this is the one that escapes me. Here is an excerpt from the HTML.

```
    </table></td>
    <td width="23" class="pbrdr"><img src="./images/boc08_line2.jpg" width="9" height="180" hspace="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="15" class="pbrdl">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="661" height="400" valign="top"><br />
    <table width="661" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
```

I want to find out which of the tables I want to access. Therefore I wrote this code.

```
Set Elems = Doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
For Each Tbl In Elems
    i = i + 1
```

By looking at `Elems(1).innerText`, with different index numbers, I found out that there are more than 10 elements to the 'Elems' collection. Some of them are nested as shown in the HTML code above. Elems(2) will include both the outer and the inner "table", whereas Elems(1) just shows the outer. But some of the inner elements are blank, and then my loop will crash out on `Next Tbl` with an "Automation error" and `Tbl = Nothing`. I was looking for a way to count the elements in the collection so that I can test. Is there such a way? It seems that the sequence by which the For ... Each loop calls its members is different from that indicated by their index numbers, though.

So, I added `On Error Resume Next` before the Next statement. Now the loop runs to i=3 sometimes and at other times to i=4. #3 is a blank. It might look like that:-

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="135" valign="top" background="./images/boc08_right4.jpg" class="brd3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

No. 4 has a lot of content. I presume that VBA doesn't keep to the same sequence on every call. However that doesn't really matter because the table I want might be after #4.

As an alternative to counting the elements I thought of a way to limit my looping to the outer "tables". `Elems.item(, 1).innerText` appears to be different from `Elems(1).innerText`. There seem to be fewer of them, but I could neither prove that they are outer "tables" nor do I know how to loop through their collection or, again, perhaps count their number before looping.

Of course, solving this problem will only get me to the next which will require me to extract a collection of the  tag from whichever "table" turns out to be the winner. But that might be my next question then.

Comment: `if tbl.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").count>0`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks for the attempt. `tbl.getElementsByTagName("table")` returns n IHTMLElementCollection which doesn't have a Count property. Just to be sure I also tested your precise code which throws an error. If counting were important there would be a Count property. All I really want and need is to isolate one tag, with everything that's in it, and then drill down to isolate another tag that resides within. It shouldn't matter what those inner tags are named as. My problem results from different levels of tags being joined in one collection.

Comment: With another approach, if I get all elements of the <td> tag, how can I separate those within the table I want from others in other tables?

Comment: Using a For ... Each loop to go through a IHTMLElementsCollection shouldn't result in an error when one of the elements isn't properly formed. On the other hand, if such an exception is unavoidable, what is the method by which I can keep the loop going? My code fails on `Next Tbl`, and `On Error Resume Next` leaves the loop. How could I construct an error handler to jump to the next member in the collection if one is a dud?